# Does the term "command" have various meanings depending on the context?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, command

I'm a junior developer struggling with a very basic knowledge in the software engineering.

I heard the term command for the first time when I studied command pattern in GoF design patterns.

But I've noticed command has to do with not only design pattern, but it also has to do with something I'm not familiar.

I found command with words such as event, command handler.
Those commands are all the same? Or Is my thought right that command has various meanings in various context?

I've googled for about three days, but with no success.
Could you help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like with the most of the terms in this industry the *Command* is also overloaded.

### Design pattern - Command

This design pattern is all about to loosely couple the caller and the callee from each other. Or by using the design pattern's terminology the invoker and the receiver.

It is done by encapsulating all information about request into a command object.

### Eventing - Command

In case of an eventing system we are differentiating *Commands* and *Events*:

- Former are requests which can be accepted & processed or rejected
- Latter are acknowledgments about the fact that a given command has been processed

A command can generate zero, one or multiple events.

### Comparison

#### Similarity

In both cases the command represents an action request

- *Please perform XYZ with the following parameters: ...*.

#### Difference

The difference is the scope of a command

- Eventing: it solely contains data without any behavioural code
- Design pattern: it contains code as well which knows how to perform a given action (`Execute`)

  - There is a variant of this design pattern which makes the action conditional (`CanExecute`)